# JSON to PDF React

Tags: json, reactjs, pdf, download

my application is having backend n Java and front-end in React.I am getting response for an API from server as JSON and rendering that to a page.l want to provide a download option with download as PDF and Excel.Can some one please guide me what will be the best option for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use stimulsoft.js for this.**

1. You have to download stimulsoft deisgner
2. You have to design a report which surely meets your json format
3. Integrate min.js of stimulsoft into your project
4. Modify it as per your requirements.

Follow the instructions given by stimulsoft.